# MySQL Get result of loading data from file

Tags: mysql, database, load-data-infile, import-from-excel

I create a procedure to load data from file into table and return the result. Here's my procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ImportData1Table`(in FilePath text, in TableName text, in DataType text)
BEGIN
    LOAD DATA INFILE FilePath INTO TABLE TableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
END 
$$
```

How can I get the query result such as

```
15824 row(s) affected Records: 15824  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched and found that LOAD DATA cannot call from store procedure.